# selenium + django in docker

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver

my Docker

```bash
FROM python:3.8-slim
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \ 
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: . 
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    image: app:django
    container_name: my_first_django_container
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

i am trying to make a website that fetch some links information from another site and update it dynamically on within the django project for this i felt the best method to deploy it would be with the help of docker

```
2024-01-03 02:30:12 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2024-01-03 02:30:15 Exception in thread django-main-thread:
2024-01-03 02:30:15 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
2024-01-03 02:30:15     self.run()
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
2024-01-03 02:30:15     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
2024-01-03 02:30:15     fn(*args, **kwargs)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
2024-01-03 02:30:15     self.check(display_num_errors=True)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
2024-01-03 02:30:15     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
2024-01-03 02:30:15     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
2024-01-03 02:30:15     return check_resolver(resolver)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
2024-01-03 02:30:15     return check_method()
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
2024-01-03 02:30:15     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2024-01-03 02:30:15     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
2024-01-03 02:30:15     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2024-01-03 02:30:15     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
2024-01-03 02:30:15     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-01-03 02:30:15     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/code/AA/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
2024-01-03 02:30:15     path('',include('zoom.urls')),
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
2024-01-03 02:30:15     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-01-03 02:30:15     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/code/zoom/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
2024-01-03 02:30:15     from . import views
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/code/zoom/views.py", line 61, in <module>
2024-01-03 02:30:15     content = scrape_website('https://aa-intergroup.org/meetings/')
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/code/zoom/views.py", line 13, in scrape_website
2024-01-03 02:30:15     driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
2024-01-03 02:30:15     super().__init__(
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
2024-01-03 02:30:15     super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__
2024-01-03 02:30:15     self.start_session(capabilities)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session
2024-01-03 02:30:15     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
2024-01-03 02:30:15     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
2024-01-03 02:30:15     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2024-01-03 02:30:15 selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
2024-01-03 02:30:15   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2024-01-03 02:30:15   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2024-01-03 02:30:15 Stacktrace:
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #0 0x55cc95251f83 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #1 0x55cc94f0acf7 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #2 0x55cc94f4260e <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #3 0x55cc94f3f26e <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #4 0x55cc94f8f80c <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #5 0x55cc94f83e53 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #6 0x55cc94f4bdd4 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #7 0x55cc94f4d1de <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #8 0x55cc95216531 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #9 0x55cc9521a455 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #10 0x55cc95202f55 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #11 0x55cc9521b0ef <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #12 0x55cc951e699f <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #13 0x55cc9523f008 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #14 0x55cc9523f1d7 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #15 0x55cc95251124 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 #16 0x7f3e1c0e5044 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:30:15 
2024-01-03 02:40:44 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2024-01-03 02:40:45 Exception in thread django-main-thread:
2024-01-03 02:40:45 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
2024-01-03 02:40:45     self.run()
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
2024-01-03 02:40:45     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
2024-01-03 02:40:45     fn(*args, **kwargs)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
2024-01-03 02:40:45     self.check(display_num_errors=True)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
2024-01-03 02:40:45     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
2024-01-03 02:40:45     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
2024-01-03 02:40:45     return check_resolver(resolver)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
2024-01-03 02:40:45     return check_method()
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
2024-01-03 02:40:45     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2024-01-03 02:40:45     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
2024-01-03 02:40:45     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2024-01-03 02:40:45     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
2024-01-03 02:40:45     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-01-03 02:40:45     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/code/AA/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
2024-01-03 02:40:45     path('',include('zoom.urls')),
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
2024-01-03 02:40:45     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-01-03 02:40:45     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/code/zoom/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
2024-01-03 02:40:45     from . import views
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/code/zoom/views.py", line 61, in <module>
2024-01-03 02:40:45     content = scrape_website('https://aa-intergroup.org/meetings/')
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/code/zoom/views.py", line 13, in scrape_website
2024-01-03 02:40:45     driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
2024-01-03 02:40:45     super().__init__(
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
2024-01-03 02:40:45     super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__
2024-01-03 02:40:45     self.start_session(capabilities)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session
2024-01-03 02:40:45     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
2024-01-03 02:40:45     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
2024-01-03 02:40:45     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2024-01-03 02:40:45 selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
2024-01-03 02:40:45   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2024-01-03 02:40:45   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2024-01-03 02:40:45 Stacktrace:
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #0 0x5578f3bcef83 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #1 0x5578f3887cf7 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #2 0x5578f38bf60e <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #3 0x5578f38bc26e <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #4 0x5578f390c80c <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #5 0x5578f3900e53 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #6 0x5578f38c8dd4 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #7 0x5578f38ca1de <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #8 0x5578f3b93531 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #9 0x5578f3b97455 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #10 0x5578f3b7ff55 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #11 0x5578f3b980ef <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #12 0x5578f3b6399f <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #13 0x5578f3bbc008 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #14 0x5578f3bbc1d7 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #15 0x5578f3bce124 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45 #16 0x7f5ea1ea8044 <unknown>
2024-01-03 02:40:45
```

These are the logs
how can i fix this issue or view the site let me know if you want more details
on my local device i used the edgedriver and i get the desired output also i am new to this so would be helpful if anyone can tell how can i deploy this thanks